# Jquery Change function not working wordpress admin dashboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working on post format select option based in WordPress. Trying to get the value of the selected option. But change method is not working. Not giving the alert value also the test alert. My code is below,

```
(function (jQuery){
    "use strict";
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery("#post-format-selector-0").change(function () {

            var selectedVal = $("#post-format-selector-0:selected").val();

            alert("Hi, your favorite programming language is " + selectedVal);

            alert("Hi, your favorite programming language is PHP ");

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: It is enqueue in admin_enqueue_scripts?

Comment: yes, outside, change function alert or console.log working

Comment: Will an alert fire outside your document.ready function?

Comment: yes, this type of alert is giving, (function (jQuery){
    "use strict";
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {  alert('this is test');   });
})(jQuery);

Comment: check if the event its there in the developer tool(f12, event listeners selecting in the dom), could be cache or simply not adding it.

Comment: is your content loading dynamicly? If yes,  you need to use like $(document).on('change','id', function (){ code here })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the **$** alias on your **change** function.  Try changing your code to:

```
(function ($){
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('change','#post-format-selector-0',function(){

            var selectedVal = $("#post-format-selector-0:selected").val();

            alert("Hi, your favorite programming language is " + selectedVal);

            alert("Hi, your favorite programming language is PHP ");

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Edit:** If you're enqueuing your script in the  header, even though you have redundant `ready` functions, the `select` element may not be loaded before the `change` function is set up. Assigning the `on` function to the `document` (or preferably, the nearest parent) allows it to fire on the `select` once it eventually shows up.

Comment: same result, not giving response

Comment: @NayeemHyderRiddhi Try rewriting your change function as I've done above.